# broken header on load sitemap.xml for google search

Tags: sitemap, google-search, xml-sitemap

sitemap.xml not work in my host:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://tcg-wallet.ga/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-12-13T17:12:22+00:00</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

located in public, and loaded via: https://tcg-wallet.ga/sitemap.xml

in network i see this:

[image]

but when i try to get it working in google search i get this:

[image]

i have test it with: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and get this:

[image]

i have try handle the content type with .htaccess but is not enough to solve the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    AddType application/xml                   xml

</IfModule>
```

---

I can't find that it is misconfigured.***

Comment: How long has it been since you made the change?  You should give Google at least two weeks after making a change.

Comment: Why are you creating a sitemap with just one page in it?  If you have just one page on your site, there is absolutely not need for a sitemap.  Sitemaps don't help with rankings.  They can get big sites crawled and they can give extra info in Google Search Console, but that is really it.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: I thought that the sitemap was necessary for google to correctly index the only view of the page, although it is possible that there will be other pages visible in the future without the need to log in.

Comment: Sitemaps rarely help indexing and never help rankings.